# Formula for Weighted Review Ratings

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis, scoring-algorithm

For my own personal calculations, I need a way to combine ratings of businesses into one weighted rating. I want my weighted rating to take into account how many people gave the rating as well as multiple ratings of said business.

Here is the data I wish to use as input:

- $G_A$ - **Google Rating:** A number rating from 1 to 5
- $G_B$ - **Google Reviewers:** Number of Google users who gave a rating
- $F_A$ - **Facebook Rating:** A number rating from 1 to 5
- $F_B$ - **Facebook Reviewers:** Number of Facebook users who gave a rating

I have come up with the following for a weighted rating formula:

$$\frac{(G_AG_B) + (F_AF_B)}{G_B + F_B}$$

The resulting numbers look good (my goal was to have them be between 1 and 5 like the original ratings), but I want to make sure - **is my equation getting a fair weighted rating?**

---

**Taking the question a little further**, I want to know if it would be feasible to take into account the following variable and, if so, how to go about adding it to the equation:

- $L$ - **Facebook Likes:** Number of likes a business has on Facebook

Comment: Did you mean to divide by $G_B + F_B$?

Comment: @B.Mehta yes thank you!